# Flutter integration tests not running on Android real device

Tags: android, flutter, integration-testing, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When attempting to run an integration test on a real device for my Flutter Android app by doing, for example:

`flutter test integration_test/name_of_test.dart`

The app doesn't open on my device, and after around two minutes, I observe the following in my terminal:

```
  Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.5.4.
  package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart 10:3                    throwToolExit
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle_utils.dart 195:3          getGradleVersionFor
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle_utils.dart 133:10         getGradleVersionForAndroidPlugin
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart 901:3                _exitWithExpectedFileNotFound
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart 461:7                AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart 179:5                AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart 579:7        AndroidDevice.startApp
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  package:flutter_tools/src/test/integration_test_device.dart 53:39  IntegrationTestTestDevice.start
02:20 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Anybody have any idea what might be going wrong>

Comment: Additionally, when I just do ```flutter test integration_test```, I am told that "No Tests Ran, No Tests Were Found"